# While building an apk using bubblewrap build its shows error Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: java, gradle, web-applications, build, progressive-web-apps

I ran `gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace`, and I get this error :

```
ERROR Command failed: gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Users\Asus\.bubblewrap\jdk\jdk8u265-b01\bin\java.exe -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Users\Asus\.bubblewrap\jdk\jdk8u265-b01\bin\java.exe -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Asus\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:176)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:137)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:217)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:211)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:133)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:145)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:99)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:294)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:266)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:259)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 7):

not sure why but commenting out the following in the **gradle.properties** file (NOT gradle-wrapper.properties) with a # got past this for me:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

so it looks like:

```
#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting this

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

solved the issue for me too, i guess that this is memory size argument which passed to the daemon process of gradle.

So, by commenting this will ignore the restricting of build.